# Is the set of upper(and separately lower)-triangular matrices a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, ring-theory

I was reading lecture notes which mentioned the set of upper (and separately lower)-triangular matrices of a certain dimensionality is a group under matrix multiplication. That made me wonder if they also form a ring under addition and multiplication.

So first, they are an abelian group under matrix addition:

- The sum of any number of triangular matrices is itself a
  triangular matrix.
- The 0 matrix is the 0 element.
- There is an additive inverse. (Element-wise negation)
- Matrix addition is commutative.

Then, they are a monoid under multiplication.

- The product of any number of triangular matrices is itself a triangular matrix.
- The identity matrix is the multiplicative identity.

And finally, multiplication distributes over addition.

Is that correct?

Comment: Your reasoning looks correct to me.

Comment: All requirements for  definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)#Definition seem to be satisfied..See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_ring

Comment: You probably mean the set of *upper* triangular matrices, not the set of upper *or* lower triangular matrices.

Comment: If: Yes. That is what I was trying to get to with "unitriangular" matrices. The set of upper-triangular matrices of a particular dimensionality and separately, the set of lower-triangular matrices of a certain dimensionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The reasoning above is correct.